# Find general formula for $a_{n+1} = \frac{a_n}{1+n a_n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

$a_{n+1} = \frac{a_n}{1+n a_n}$

$a_0=1$

Series: $1, 1/2, 1/4, 1/7, 1/11, 1/16...$ ( we ca rewrite as $a_{n+1} = \frac{1}{\frac{1}{a_n}+n}$)

By wolfram alpha answer is $\frac{2}{(n-1)^2+n+1}$

I have no idea how to get it manually.

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**. From
$$
a_{n+1} = \frac{1}{\frac{1}{a_n}+n}
$$ you get
$$
\frac1{a_n}-\frac1{a_{n+1}}=-n
$$ then use a *telescoping* sum and a standard sum.

Answer (score 2):

Let $b_n=1/a_n$ and find the recurrence satisfied by it.