# Finding a value on the 2306th number of a sequence, and subtracting a number from it.

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

I've been struggling on this question, since it involves large numbers and I don't deal very good with them.

Consider a sequence of numbers ${a_n}$ defined by: $$a_1 = 1$$ and: $$a_{n+1} = \frac{a_n}{1+na_n}$$

It already began to look complicated, but it's not the most complicated thing to me, the problem asks to get the value of: $$\frac{1}{a_{2306}} - 2657666$$

First of all, I would have to deal with the outstanding number $2306$ (in the base of $a$ in the last expression). If it were to have $6$ or $10$, I would just use brute force, but this is way too much.

The only thing I'm confused about is how to evaluate a number from a sequence that is placed so far down the sequence, there should be a general method, and if someone were to teach it to me, I could also apply the same concept or similarly to other problems with the same general idea. What I'm looking for is how to go pass the roadblock described above, so I would be very grateful if you explained it to me.

Thank you for all help.

Comment: Well, an obvious first thing to try is to compute a few values.  The pattern becomes clear pretty quickly.

Comment: Hint: $ \dfrac{a+b}{c} =\dfrac{a}{c}+\dfrac{b}{c} $

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find general formula for $a_{n+1} = \frac{a_n}{1+n a_n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1758054/find-general-formula-for-a-n1-fraca-n1n-a-n) – found [with Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24a_%7Bn%2B1%7D%20%3D%20%5Cfrac%7Ba_n%7D%7B1%2Bna_n%7D%24)

Comment: $99.99999$% (roughly) of the time when you are asked to calculate the $n$th term of a recurrence relation (that isn't linear) with astronomical $n$ then there is some pattern that will be quite visible say in the first 10 terms which you'll be able to apply to find the $n$th term. Be adventurous! :)